# Why is Object.keys([,1,,1]) different from Object.keys([,1,undefined,1])?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was shocked that the result of

```js
document.writeln(Object.keys([,1,,1]));
```

is

```
1,3
```

which filters the index of an array that doesn't contains anything automatically. But when I try to print out Object.keys([,1,undefined,1]):

```js
document.writeln(Object.keys([,1,undefined,1]));
```

the result is:

```
1,2,3
```

which is different from the previous one, and I try to print the value of index 2 at the first one:

```js
document.writeln([,1,,1][2]);
```

which is undefined actually. Why would Object.keys([,1,,1]) and Object.keys([,1,undefined,1]) return different results?

Comment: if you `console.log` the 2 arrays you'll notice a difference, first one shows `<1 empty slot>` where second shows `undefined`. The array is made such as to return `undefined` when you try to access an empty slot, but that's not the value in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Object.keys([, 1, undefined, 1])` case, you are explicitly defining the third element to be `undefined`, but in `Object.keys([, 1, , 1])`, there is no element associated with the index `2`. So, `2` is recognized as an array index in the first case, but not in the second case.

Just to represent the holes in the array, when you actually reference it, `undefined` is returned. That is why `[, 1, , 1][2]` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

This is one caveat to be careful with Javascript arrays : you can have **sparse arrays**, arrays with *missing values*, which is not the same as having `undefined` *values* (the array element exists, like a variable can be declared, but it's value is `undefined).

Note that you can get the same behavior using `delete` on an array element.

As already said, you can test for empty value wiht `=== undefined`, which is even more confusing, because it does not usually cause the same output.

Answer (score 0):

You're right to think that it doesn't make much sense. It doesn't. Basically, in javascript there is *sometimes* a difference between "undefined" and "has never been defined". In the first example, you're not giving the second index any value, so it doesn't print. In the second example, you're giving it a value (even though that value is undefined, it's still getting *a* value) so it prints it.